# As a Jenkins Build Server Admin what all things I must take care of?

Tags: linux, jenkins

I have recently set up a Jenkins build server on a Linux VM. As the Jenkins admin what all things I must take care of?

There is a list of best practices [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Best+Practices) but please take a note I am looking for the must haves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats my personal list:

- Secure Jenkins (restrict access to the users)
- monitor the resource usage (CPU / RAM / Disk) we used to push the data to graphite and monitor it with grafana.
- if resource usage exceeds the available resources, use slaves
- don't schedule all jobs at the same time
- try to use the pipeline plugin https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/
- Backup the JENKINS_HOME regurarly
- use the portable file name character set for job names http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_282
- try to automate the setup of a master / slave (docker, ansible ...) so you can recreate your instance somewhere else with no time loss.